# max min ODD numbers from a sequence without arrays

Tags: java

I am trying to get the max and min ODD numbers from sequence of inputs without using an array, please advise what should I add, I am using the below code:

```
System.out.print("Enter odd integers(even to Stop): " );

do {
    num = input.nextInt();
    sum += num;
} while (num % 2 != 0);

if (num < min) {
    min = num;                
}
if (num > max) {
    max = num;
}

System.out.print("Minimum Odd Number: " + min + ";");
System.out.println("Maximum Odd Number: " + max);
System.out.print("Sum: " + sum);
```

Comment: Just place your two `if` statements inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic to check the odd value, to possibly record it as a min or max, should be *inside* the loop:

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

int num = input.nextInt();

while (num % 2 != 0) {
    sum += num;

    if (num < min) {
        min = num;                
    }
    if (num > max) {
         max = num;
    }

    num = input.nextInt();
}

System.out.print("Minimum Odd Number: " + min + ";");
System.out.println("Maximum Odd Number: " + max);
System.out.print("Sum: " + sum);
```

As a comment, I initialize the `min` and `max` integers to the largest and smallest integer values, respectively.  This ensures that we correctly capture the very first inputs, whatever they might be.

Comment: Thanks Tim, it works! However for the Sum variable, I need to exclude the final even number, now it add all the numbers including the final even one

Comment: @khelwood I don't see a nice way of phrasing this.  You may post if you have a better way.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, I think I'd use a break too.

Comment: initialize `num` with `0` and do `sum += num` before you read the next number (first statement in the do while loop)

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Exactly this what I did and it works thanks! I just still need to check if the sum is divisible by the last integer entered which is an even integer

Comment: @JohannesKuhn We can try making first an initial read of the input number.  But it seems slightly ugly to duplicate this line.

Comment: Declare `lastNum` outside of the loop, assign `lastNum` to `num` as first/second statement in the loop. Use `lastNum` to check if the `sum` is divisible.

Answer (score -1):

This will work. If there aren't any odd numbers given min and max will be 0:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = 0, sum = 0, max = 0, min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
System.out.print("Enter odd integers(even to Stop): ");
do {
    num = input.nextInt();
    if (num < min) {
        min = num;
    }
    if (num > max) {
        max = num;
    }
    sum += num;
} while (num % 2 != 0);
if(min % 2 == 0) min = 0;
if(max % 2 == 0) max = 0;
System.out.print("Minimum Odd Number: " + min + ";");
System.out.println("Maximum Odd Number: " + max);
System.out.print("Sum: " + sum);
input.close();
```